# Oracle DB displays data

Tags: database, oracle

Having a hard time figuring this, how to display "name" using only like 3 letter string. example below.

```
$query = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM STAFF_DETAILS WHERE NAME = '$name'  "); 

if(oci_execute($query))
  {                             
     while(($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_BOTH)) != false)
      {
        echo $row['NAME']; 
      }
   }
```

the problem is you can display only the fullname (ex. Zach De La Rocha), what i want is to display all names begins "Zach" only.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question, it would help if you could be a little clearer. Just guessing, if you are asking how you can select only the records where the name begins with 'Zach', the Oracle syntax is:

```
...where name like 'Zach%'
```

The % in the expression above means "anything may come after Zach". Since there is no % before Zach, that means Zach must be at the **beginning** of name.

Comment: great! thanks man, just missing the "%" sign, geez..thanks a lot

Comment: Hi - this still shows up as unanswered, you may want to mark it answered. Cheers!